# PHP Fatal error: Internal zval's can't be arrays

Tags: php, iis

I'm getting this error on my php yii application using `IIS` server. I understand it's a PHP error and it comes about when using windows server like myself. It always appears at the bottom of the page however it doesn't cause any actual errors on my system. Is there a way I can remove this without any updates. Even if it means hiding it somehow?
I'm not even sure what the full error is this is all I get in full

```
PHP  Fatal  error:  Internal zval's  can't be  arrays, objects or resources in Unknown on line 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Which version of php are you running on that server?

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.21


System Windows NT NS4 6.0 build 6002 (Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition Service Pack 2) i586

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a faulty extension.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Yii` application suggest `apache` as web server.